# Swift - Execute performSegue under conditions

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My intention is to run `performSegue` solely if all textfields are filled. If not, the button is not supposed to work - to be exact, `performSegue` shall not be executed.

My approach was to put `performSegue` inside of an if statement, but somehow it's being ignored and `performSegue` is being executed anyways, even though both fields are empty. Is there another more successful approach?

```
@IBAction func buttonAdd(_ sender: Any) {
        if (addKmInput.text! != "" && addPriceInput.text != "") {
            ...
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "goBackToSecond", sender: self)
        }
    }
```

```
@IBOutlet weak var addKmInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var addPriceInput: UITextField!
```

New version:

```
@IBAction func buttonAdd(_ sender: Any) {        
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goBackToSecond", sender: self)
    }

override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        switch identifier {
        case "goBackToSecond":
            return shouldGoBackToSecond()
        default:
            return true
        }
    }

func shouldGoBackToSecond() -> Bool {
        guard let kmInput = addKmInput.text, let priceInput = addPriceInput.text else { return false }
        return !kmInput.isEmpty && !priceInput.isEmpty
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following solution:

```
@IBAction func buttonAdd(_ sender: Any) {
    if shouldGoBackToSecond() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goBackToSecond", sender: self)
    }
}

func shouldGoBackToSecond() -> Bool {
    guard let kmInput = addKmInput.text, let priceInput = addPriceInput.text else { return false }
    return !kmInput.isEmpty && !priceInput.isEmpty
}
```

Comment: I'm new to swift - I get the following error: `Expected 'else' after 'guard' condition`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've updated the initial question with the new version of the code - somehow it still executes performSegue and changes ViewController

Comment: Lets have a [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192152/room-for-tomas-jablonskis-and-tim-fuhrmann)

Comment: *Summary of chat:* fixed the issue by ignoring `shouldPeformSegue` function and writing an if condition at  `buttonAdd(...)` function.

Answer (score 0):

use  `str.isEmpty` to check if the string int he textField is empty :

```
if let t1 = addKmInput?.text, let t2 = addPriceInput?.text, !t1.isEmpty, !t2.isEmpty {
        ...
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goBackToSecond", sender: self)
}
```

and you should ideally use this delegate to deny segue performance:

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool { 
    return true //return true/false conditionally. returning false will prevent segue performance. 
}
```